# Sybpydb error 5701 ignored sometimes

Tags: python, sybase, sap-ase

I have come across a very strange behavior when developing an application in Python (2.7.11) using a Sybase ASE 15.7 database and the sybpydb library.

When selecting data from the database there is always an error 5701 thrown that isn´t an error but just a informational message taht the client has logged on or changed database.

This should be ignored by the client and it works fine most of the time but sometimes not.

Has anyone come across this problem and know a way to work around it?
I don´t want to stop handling exceptions.

The following code illustrates the problem, the first two queries runs as the should but the last one doesn´t work, I have checked the query and yes it returns a result set.

```
uname = 'username'
pwd = 'password'
server = 'server'


conn = sybpydb.connect(user=uname, password=pwd, servername=server)
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    sql = 'select * from database..table1'
    cur.execute(sql)
    print 'Execute for table1'
    print cur.connection.errors()
    
    row = cur.fetchone()
    print "Query Returned %d row(s)" % cur.rowcount
    print row
except sybpydb.Error:
    print cur.connection.errors()
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


conn = sybpydb.connect(user=uname, password=pwd, servername=server)
cur = conn.cursor()
parameter1 = 'DSE'
try:
    sql = 'select * from database..table2 where column1 = ?'
    cur.execute(sql, [parameter1])
    print 'Execute for table2'
    print cur.connection.errors()

    row = cur.fetchone()
    print "Query Returned %d row(s)" % cur.rowcount
    print row
except sybpydb.Error:
    print cur.connection.errors()
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

parameter1 = 1
parameter2 = 1
conn = sybpydb.connect(user=uname, password=pwd, servername=server)
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    sql = 'select * from database..table3 where column1 = ? and column2 ?'
    cur.execute(sql, [parameter1, parameter2])
    print 'Execute for table3'
    print cur.connection.errors()

    row = cur.fetchone()
    print "Query Returned %d row(s)" % cur.rowcount
    print row
except sybpydb.Error:
    print cur.connection.errors()
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

These three calls to the database results in this.

> Execute for table1
>
> [DatabaseError("Server message: number(5701) severity(10) state(2) line(0)\n\tChanged database context to 'master'.\n\n", 5701)]
>
> Query Returned -1 row(s)
>
> (Resultset for query 1)
>
> Execute for table2
>
> [DatabaseError("Server message: number(5701) severity(10) state(2) line(0)\n\tChanged database context to 'master'.\n\n", 5701)]
>
> Query Returned -1 row(s)
>
> (Resultset for query2)
>
> [DatabaseError("Server message: number(5701) severity(10) state(2) line(0)\n\tChanged database context to 'master'.\n\n", 5701)]

Answer (score 0):

I never get such message when using sybpydb , I don't print cur.connection.errors() , which is not one of the documented [methods](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01692.1570/doc/html/car1309464785662.html) (I even got an error when I tried to use it )

In all cases ,maybe you are getting this message as part of Sybase ASE informing the client about:

1- Default database when you log in - I don't think this applied to python .

2- when you change the database context .. which you are doing by specifying "database.."

To get rid of this message , simply set a default database for the user you use to connect as the target database , hence , you connection will be located immediately in that database after login and you don't need to specify the database in the query anymore , to change default database for login use :

```
sp_modifylogin <uname>, defdb, "<database>"
```

or in ASE 15.7 :

```
alter login <uname> modify default database <database>
```

then your queries should look like :

```
sql = 'select * from table3 where column1 = ? and column2 ?'
```

Comment: I actually solved it yesterday. The problem was that i had used cur.connection.errors(), I don't know where I got that from. There was another error that didn´t get printed out after the 5701. When I sorted that out the application works as it should. Unfortunately the application is using a generic user at this moment so I have to live with the 5701 at the moment.